# optimization in symfony2 code without having to search for ID first

Tags: php, symfony

I have an entity called InstagramTag which is very basic and simple:

```
class InstagramTag
{
     /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="tag", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $tag;

     /**
     *
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\MainBundle\Entity\InstagramPictureTag", mappedBy="tag")
     */
    protected $picturetag;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get tag
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTag()
    {
        return $this->tag;
    }

    /**
     * Set tag
     *
     * @param string $tag
     * @return InstagramTag
     */
    public function setTag( $tag)
    {
        $this->tag = $tag;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

and I have this routine that basically check if InstagramTag with a particular tag already exists or not. If it doesn't exist then create one, so the code looks like this:

```
    foreach ($image->tags as $tag) {
        $existingTag = $this->em->getRepository('AppMainBundle:InstagramTag')->findOneByTag($tag);
        $instaPictureTag = new InstagramPictureTag();
        $instaPictureTag->setPicture($instaShopPicture);

        if ($existingTag) {
            $instaPictureTag->setTag($existingTag);
        } else {
            $instagramTag = new InstagramTag();
            $instagramTag->setTag($tag);
            $this->em->persist($instagramTag);
            $instaPictureTag->setTag($instagramTag);
        }       

        $this->em->persist($instaPictureTag);             
    }
```

The code is relatively slow since the InstagramTag table is of 1.6 million entries. So searching just for 1 tag takes about 1.3 second on MySQL table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `MySQL` is a bottle neck in your case. So what I would advice is not to check if tag exists inside `foreach` loop because you query `mySql` each iteration of loop.

Instead I would create [custom repository](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) method which will find entities for all tags at once (so you call `mySQL` only once)

```
public function getRowsByTags(array $tags)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
            ->andWhere('i.tag IN (:tags)')
            ->setParameter(':tags', $tags)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
}
```

This way you get collection of `InstagramTag` entities. Then, inside your foreach loop you need to iterate over this collection (you iterate in memory, without touching your slow mysql), check if your `InstagramTag` is there. If not, you need to create new one.

Other question here is if you have your `tag` column indexed properly in mysql as this is quite slow.

Comment: The last line is the real answer.  Index your tag.  1.6 million records is trivial when properly indexed.  Using an IN clause is still a good idea but indexing is the key.  http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-index